# Why the select tag errors in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

Well, I'm blocked with this, I have an JSP with 2 forms, one of them is to look for Pets according to an `id` of the customer, and the other is to register a service for one of those Pets, so the problem is that when I look for the Pets with the following form, which is linked to a `PetsAction`:

```jsp
<s:form action="searchPets">
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" name="customer.id" class="form-ontrol">              
</div>
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

I have a problem with a select tag, that is loaded by first time with data from the `prepare()` method of the `ServiceAction`, when the data from the form "searchPets" come to the JSP.

```jsp
<s:select list="employees"
name="GrooService.employee.IdEmp"
listKey="IdEmp"
listValue="nameEmp"
cssClass="form-control"
id="GrooList"
/>
```

This is the error that I get

```jsp
tag 'select', field 'list', name 'GrooService.employee.IdEmp': 
The requested list key 'employees' could not be resolved as a 
collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. 
Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
```

So, what should I modify? Is it correct if I load the data of the select tag from the `PetsAction` too? Should I have just one action for both forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as both actions return the same result JSP which contains a `select` tag and different action classes hold the action method you have to write `prepare()` in both classes.

Otherwise you can use one action class for both actions/methods.

The exception is thrown because the `list` attribute of the [`<s:select>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/select-tag.html) couldn't be `null`. You should properly initialize the variable used for the tag before returning a result that has references to that variable.

Comment: So do you think is correct to use one Action class for both? Have you ever had this situation before?

Comment: Theoretically you can write whole application in one action class, but in my experience preferable to separate it on different classes. It's up to you how do you organize them. All you should know that JSPs are action's `dispatcher` result and the action is responsible to initialize/populate objects used to render that JSP.

Comment: @Gianfranco If it worked for you, and this answer helped you to do so, you should mark it as accepted. See [How it works](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).